# Javascript/Jquery flow text into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

How do I flow a text stream from one div to the next? Each div has a fixed height and width and I need the data to be passed to the first, then if that is filled overflow to another etc. (The second etc. divs need to be dynamically created). Eventually the divs will be contenteditable, this is the page technique for a simple WYSIWYG style editor.

Please help...

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adminb/kT59T/) (note zoom in use on body)(I need to reflow on keyup/down, make pages and remove as necessary and be able to add in the middle)

```
function loadgo(){
    run();
    var h = document.getElementById('page'+(document.getElementById("pagecount").value-1)).offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("loadgo").value = h+1;
    if (h > 1135){
        var pagecount = document.getElementById("pagecount").value;
        //$('body').append("<div class=page style='color:#F00' id='page"+pagecount+"' contenteditable>"+this.id+"</div>");
            var objTo = document.body;
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.style.color = '#F00';
            divtest.id = "page"+pagecount;
            divtest.className = 'page';
            divtest.contentEditable = "true";
            divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
            objTo.appendChild(divtest);
        document.getElementById("page"+pagecount).focus();
        document.getElementById("pagecount").value++;
        zoomin();zoomout();
        run();
    }
}
function run(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        loadgo();
    }, 500);
}
loadgo();
```

Comment: some code examples or a jsfiddle would help us understand your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called CSS Regions. This allows your text to flow through various containers placed on your site.

You can read about it on [Adobe's site](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/), and Apple has a nice [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=600) explaining how to implement it (starts at 8:40). Also check out the [Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/).

Comment: How can I actually implement CSS regions? I'm completely confused by it! Also does it only work in iOS7, I need a cross-browser alternative if so.

Comment: If you need cross-browser support, CSS Regions is not your solution right now. The only browsers that support it - desktop and mobile - are Safari 7 on OS X and iOS 7, with partial support in IE 10-11 and IE mobile 10 (Windows Phone?). See [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=region)